# For the people who are treated with interferons, does this provide them extra protection against corona virus?

Tags: covid-19, coronavirus, antivirals

It is known that interferon inhibits the viruses replication process. At the same time, they don't give it to people with COVID-19 because we don't want the flu-like symptoms to get worse. How about the people who receive interferon for other diseases? Is this an advantage? or Do they have more protection than other people who don't take interferon? If you want me to be specific let's talk about Interferon Beta-1a but I'm talking generally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No one knows. It’s possible, and there are clinical trial underway to determine any effect eg https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/health-52504409